Activator.CreateInstance throwing exception for Anonymous Type object with parameters
private dynamic GetAnonymousItemData(Type anonType, OracleDataReader reader)
{
    var item = new object[reader.FieldCount];
    for (int i = 0; i < reader.FieldCount; i++)
    {

        item[i] = reader[i];
        if (i == 0)
        {
            item[i] = Convert.ToInt64(reader[i]);
        }
        else
        {
            item[i] = Convert.ToString(reader[i]);
        }
    }

    var temp = new object[] { 1, "Test", "test" };

    dynamic? itemTestTemp = Activator.CreateInstance(anonType, temp);
    dynamic? itemTest = Activator.CreateInstance(anonType, item);

    return itemTest ?? new object();
}

I have the above code, but it throws error on itemTest and works fine on itemTestTemp.
The Exception that I get:

System.MissingMethodException: Constructor on type '<>f__AnonymousType0`3[[System.Int32, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e],[System.String, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e],[System.String, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]]' not found.

I want the itemTest to work same as itemTestTemp, I tried different solutions from the web but nothing worked.
Sorry for bad English, it is not my native language

The code you provided is neither minimal nor reproducible. You either need to reduce your issue to smallest possible amount of code to reproduce (this is generally a good troubleshooting practice anyway) or provide more context, specifically what is anonType and what data comes in itemTest at the point when the exception is thrown. This is not dissimilar to reducing the code as this will necessarily eliminate all the additional, unrelated things like the for loop and data reader. In addition, the difference between the arrays should become clear to you at this point.

It might also be that you're not actually looking for a way to construct a specific anonymous type with any data from the data reader (as that does not seem very practical) but instead to create an ad hoc object (i.e. dynamic/ExpandoObject) for any shape of data that comes from the reader. Unfortunately, this context was also left out of your question.

Are you sure it's failing on itemTest? The message says it can't find a constructor with signature (int, string, string) which is exactly what itemTestTemp is. This is not the same as item, which will need (long, params string[]) which would appear to work for both your cases. So what constructors does AnonymousType have?

I apologize for my English and not asking the question clearly. Although I solved it, the problem was Convert.ToInt64(reader[i]), as I converted the value to Int64 but the anonymous type was asking for Int32 in the constructor. Thank You

This is a very bad way of working with anon types. Actually, for output, most ways are bad ways, since it demands template arguments to trick the compiler. Have you considered named value tuples instead? Or tools like Dapper or EF that can take this strain for you, using more reasonable approaches?

Actually, I am developing my own ORM for a bank as they do not rely on 3rd party code, so using Dapper or EF is not an option and so is using value tuples because then I will have to write a function that converts that value tuple to the required LINQ anon type and that will become an overhead
